# How to break out of a switch in octave?

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, octave, break

It seems to be that in `octave` (and perhaps also `matlab`) there is no way to break out of a `switch` statement, but I am not sure...

```
P=rand(2,20);
mu=mean(P,2);
dim=2;
plot_mean=false;

for i=1:1

switch (dim)
case 2
        % Print points as dots
        plot(P(1,:),P(2,:),'.');
        if (!plot_mean)
                break;
        endif
        hold on
        % Print mean values as red circles
        plot(mu(1,:),mu(2,:),'or');
        % Quite some more code following here with again several if statements that need to be broken out
case 3
        % Similar for 3D case
        % ...
endswitch

endfor
```

I just made this question into a full `octave` program, feel free to replace the `plot` functionality with other function calls. What is important is that I added a `for` loop around it from `1:1` and use `break`, but this is of course just a trick!

What is the normal way to break out of `switch` in `octave`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed the point of your question but `break` is only for loops. Is this what you're trying to do:

```
switch (dim)
case 2
        % Print points as dots
        plot(P(1,:),P(2,:),'.');
        if (plot_mean)
            hold on
            % Print mean values as red circles
            plot(mu(1,:),mu(2,:),'or');
        end
case 3
```

Because otherwise it sounds like you're trying to implement a "goto"-like statement which is bad practice. Rather restructure your code (as above).

I would think that this is not possible because as your hack seems to indicate, you can `break` from a loop that contains a `switch` from within one of the cases. This is possible because Octave/Matlab doesn't have the same fall through behaviour as C. These forum posts seem to agree, but this is hardly conclusive proof:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5718-use-of-break-in-switch-statement
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/128319

But to answer your question of what is the *normal* way to break from a switch in Octave, I would say the *normal* way is to encapsulate your code in `if` statements.

Comment: Those switch statements are quite large. So, I want to break out of them. A `break` for a `switch` statement exists in many languages and I am wondering if I missed it in `octave`.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you should refactor your code then, you can break out of a linear piece of code like a switch. You will need to encapsulate the code you wish to skip in an `if` statement (like in my example, on longer and possibly with more `if`s)

Comment: The `break` in C# for example is only because the switch will run through all the other code if it's not there. It's so that you can have many conditions execute the same code (i.e. `case 1: case 4: case 9: do stuff; break;`), I don't think it's there to use to skip code within a case. That sounds like a pretty bad idea to me.

Comment: The `break` in C/C#/C++ in a switch is functional as well. Not just a fancy thing that separates cases.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm saying I don't think that that's it's intended use. I mean, it's not necessary. In a loop the `break` can stop you running say 1000000 loops of nothing (which could waste time). In a switch it's just going to skip like 4 or 5 `if`s, so why make your code nonlinear for no benefit?

Comment: I know assembly. A case is just a goto statement. 

Anyway, my question is about the presence/absence of a break-like statement in a switch in `octave`. I think it is absent then. :-)

Comment: goto is unavoidable in assembly, it's really not advised in higher level languages. I don't think that switches are gotos, I think that the interpreter will run through each case consecutively and treat it as a condition. Sure a condition may compile down to a goto, but explicitly programming with a goto in high level languages is generally ill advised. Maybe you can do it in Octave (like your hack), but I think you should rather just refactor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59188/discussion-between-anne-van-rossum-and-dan).